# c# html hyperlink call a method

Tags: c#, methods, hyperlink

is it possible to call a method using a regular hyperlink like so:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href=#> click this </a></li>
<li><a href=#> click this again </a></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

call this method:

```
protected void menuPersonTab_OnMenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    mvPerson.ActiveViewIndex = Int32.Parse(menuPersonTab.SelectedValue);
}
```

no? yes?

Comment: I believe you can add an OnClick handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a ID="MyAnchor"
    OnServerClick="menuPersonTab_OnMenuItemClick" 
    runat="server"> Click This </a>
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.serverclick%28VS.90%29.aspx) is an explained example from MSDN.

Comment: this gives me a CS1501: No overload for method 'menuPersonTab_OnMenuItemClick' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Create  "protected void menuPersonTab_OnMenuItemClick()" function with 0 arguments

Answer (score 0):

In real C#, no because .Net framework handles all the javascript and post-back
But there is always a work around...
But Microsoft doesn't recommend that

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<%# menuPersonTab_OnMenuItemClick(); %>">Click this</a>
```

Comment: it gives me a > Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: Did you try using = instead of #?

Comment: That method is a void and I don't think gdubs meant to output anything inside the href from the method.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you want the C# code executed:

**On the server:**
If your server is an ASP.Net server, you can execute any method on the server, by making a new request. If you use WebForms just add a server side control. Using MVC, a new request goes through an Action method.

**On the client**

Method 1: Host the webbrowser control in your C# application. You control the browser. So you can do (almost) all you want.

Method 2: Add an ActiveX (yuc) or Silverlight control to the page. You run in a sandbox, but it is possible to catch the click event, and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are few possible ways to do it. But they are strongly not reccomended.
One of them calling onclick __doPostBack ("elementId","parameters") function.

```
<a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')">LinkButton</a>
```

Comment: If you are not able to attach server side event to code(for example - HTML code is creating by Javascript) but you need to call server event - you can call javascript function __doPostBack with needed parameters. __doPostBack will post back data to server where you can process it and call necessary function.